# Shatnez Lab Service

Tags: clothing, shaatnez

I currently live in an area which does not have a Jewish community, let alone  a lab for checking shatnez. Is there a reliable place in which I could send my clothing to check for shatnez?

Comment: I'd suggest CYLOR (though clearly may not be that local) which/if any clothing you need to check for *shatnez* before you go to such lengths.

Comment: Indeed if the obligation stems from a Miut HaMatzui there may be leniencies regarding how far out of your way you have to go to check

Comment: @DoubleAA - Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ezra you'll find the discussion more by bugs, but in short if the majority of stuff is kosher (uninfested, not shaatnez) then Deorayta you don't need to check. If a significant minority is problematic then a rabbinic obligation to check comes into effect. Rabbinic rules are more lenient than biblical ones in various ways. Arguably the rabbinic obligation is to make a reasonable effort not to get the problematic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flatbush Shatnez Center can be contacted at 718-382-5689. You can ship your garments to them and they will ship it back to you.

You should call them first as they will guide you as to which articles of clothing need to be sent. Certain clothing may not need to be inspected and certain brands they can tell you from experience that it does not require inspection.